# Git seeing file changes on files that I can't access because of differing umlaut-encodings?

Tags: git, macos, utf-8, character-encoding

I am currently having a massive problem with my git. I have a cloned git repository, and it is tracking files that are behaving very weird.

It's all about two files, that are called `Lebensstiltagebuch_Frühstück_1.jpg` and `Lebensstiltagebuch_Frühstück_2.jpg`.

Git always tells me, that they have changed, and that I should clean my working tree before I can pull something new. But whatever I do, these two files stay in the `Changes not staged for commit:` list:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   "Lebensstiltagebuch_Fru\314\210hstu\314\210ck_1.jpg"
    modified:   "Lebensstiltagebuch_Fru\314\210hstu\314\210ck_2.jpg"
```

I already tried to do:

- `git reset --hard HEAD`, to discard all untracked changes, but it did nothing
- `git rm --cached Lebensstiltagebuch_Frühstück_2.jpg`

But nothing worked.
I also tried to remove the existing file from the folder, then the list looks like this:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    deleted:    "Lebensstiltagebuch_Fr\303\274hst\303\274ck_1.jpg"
    deleted:    "Lebensstiltagebuch_Fr\303\274hst\303\274ck_2.jpg"

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   "Lebensstiltagebuch_Fru\314\210hstu\314\210ck_1.jpg"
    modified:   "Lebensstiltagebuch_Fru\314\210hstu\314\210ck_2.jpg"

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    "Lebensstiltagebuch_Fr\303\274hst\303\274ck_1.jpg"
    "Lebensstiltagebuch_Fr\303\274hst\303\274ck_2.jpg"
```

Here I can see that the files I am working on have a different filename when decoded (?), then end is `\274ck_2.jpg` vs `\210ck_2.jpg`.

Although I was working on the same file all the time, and in finder and also when running `ls -la` in terminal, the file names are exactly the same, but with `ü,ö,ä`, as I am german...

I am working on macOS 12 Beta. Does someone have a clue how to solve this issue?

Comment: `\303\274` is octal representation of UTF-8 byte sequence for `ü` _Latin Small Letter U With Diaeresis_ while `u\314\210` is similar for [decomposed](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) `u` _Latin Small Letter U_ followed by ```̈``` _Combining Diaeresis_. I have no clue for such [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case in `git`…

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: try setting `core.precomposeUnicode` to `true` or `false`.

> [Is this because of differing umlaut encodings?]

Yes.  [JosefZ has pinpointed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69723271/git-seeing-file-changes-on-files-that-i-cant-access-because-of-differing-umlaut#comment123250041_69723271): `\303\274` is one way to encode a lowercase U with an umlaut (as a single "rune", as Go would call it), and `u\314\210` is another, different way to encode a lowercase U with an umlaut (two separate "runes", as Go would call them).

The root issue is that on Linux systems, you can use *either spelling*—composed, as in the first case, or de-composed, as in the second—but macOS insists on just one spelling: the decomposed form.  (Most Linux software leans towards using the composed form, but the OS doesn't *insist* one way or the other.  You can in fact store two *different* files whose name *appears* the same, but one file is spelled one way, and the other spelled the other.)

The actual repository has whatever the repository has.  The `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` files have whatever they have.  But the file *in the file system*, in your *working tree*, on macOS will be spelled with the decomposed form.  The OS insists.  You cannot make it behave otherwise.  You can only have *one* file name whose displayed character is `ü` here, using the decomposed form.

Whether or not there are any changes in the binary file—which may or may not be treated *as* a binary file in the first place, depending on the `.gitattributes` settings, which might not match the way the file is being stored *as a file* in your macOS working tree—and whether or not you actually *change* the file's name and/or contents *in Git* when you use `git add` are separate questions, each with its own separate answer.

Git has one knob specific to macOS:

```
core.precomposeUnicode
```

You can use `git config` to set this option to `true` to tell Git to "undo" the decomposition and use the composed form for file names stored in Git's index.  (I assume, but have not tested, that this applies to `.gitattributes` as well, if/as necessary.)

The thing is, this should already be set to `true`.  If so, you can set it to `false` instead.  If the Linux system is using decomposed file names, this is what you will need to do.

For more about this, see https://www.git-tower.com/help/guides/faq-and-tips/faq/unicode-filenames/mac (which goes into more detail and provides some ways to test this out for yourself when you have both Linux and macOS available).  Note that this page spells the knob `core.precomposeunicode` (all lower case), but the case of letters in Git config settings is irrelevant, so you can spell it `coRE.pRecoMPOseUNIcode` if you like.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>My personal preference is generally "all lowercase", so that my pinky finger does not get tired of pressing the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key so much.  This also sidesteps the question of how to uppercase the ß character.  But Git uses camelCase, a la Go programming.